# How To Disable visual fill before input finish?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utn5E.png)

when I'm input Chinese in SoftWrap Mode, VSCode auto fill the full line and move the cursor to the end of line. Hot to disable it?

I could not find a way to disable it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Vgv.gif)

Comment: what do you mean by "fill the full line"? Can you describe each step of what you're seeing and doing?

Comment: You can see the picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utn5E.png . when you type a long line with soft wrap, VSCode will fill current line with content before. @user

Comment: ... before what?

Comment: see this gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Vgv.gif . when I input characters, cursor is in it's origin position. when I input Chinese, the cursor is push to to the end of line, while the content of previous line fill the current line

Comment: it's quite hard for me to understand the problem because I've never used a chinese IME. It might help if you describe exactly sequence of events you expect/want to happen.